# Is there a difference between IE conditionals `>-->` and `><!-->`?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

Is there a difference between ending the first line of an IE conditional comment with
`>-->` versus `><!-->`?

**Examples**:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
    THIS----^^^^
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Versus...

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    THIS----^^^^^^
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Both approaches result in exactly the same code being commented out, so
I am wondering where these two barely-different constructs came from.

MSDN [suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms537512.aspx#syntax) `>-->`, but I've seen `><!-->` in many blog posts and
SO answers.

Is there a particularly stubborn browser out there that chokes on
Microsoft's suggested `>-->` construct?

What's the reason for this fracture?

**Edit**: Through some non-thorough testing I found that `>-->` did not work properly in IE9, but `><!-->` did work.

Comment: IMO they're is just **both wrong**, it should be `<!--[if !IE]>` (downlevel hidden). First one closes comment then it's meaningless (HTML inside conditional comment will be visible to all browsers). Second one open a new comment (but in HTML you can't have nested comments) so IE9 will accept and ignore it (with an extra orphan `>`) just because it's allowed to put everything in a single line.

Comment: @Adriano you should post that as an answer probably

Comment: @Joeytje50 I thought but I'm pretty lazy to write it down in a proper way, expand it little bit and with a (more or less) decent English. If someone else will do it then I'll give my +1!

Comment: @Adriano I just went ahead and assumed that was meant as an invitation for me to do it, since I was the only other person to comment on it :P

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for conditional comments is as follows:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    Foo
<![endif]-->
```

So all other syntaxes are wrong.

What your mentioned syntaxes would do is close the comment right after the condition, so both of those would have no effect at all. The HTML parser recognises the `-->` that occurs in both of the examples you gave, so it will stop parsing it as a comment right away, so it will show whatever's after that as normal HTML.

If you look at the [url you provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms537512.aspx#syntax) this is also the same as what MSDN says. The code examples provide a good list of examples, so if you copy those directly, it should work just fine.

Comment: The examples I posted in my question are not incorrect.  They work as expected in IE 7, 8, 9, 10, Chrome, and Firefox.